# Incorrect Android documentation about layout aliases?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to figure out how to reuse or "alias" layouts with the least boilerplate code.

It seems that the [Android documentation about layout aliases](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) is incorrect, and certainly appears inconsistent.  This section of documentation shows the following layout file as an example:

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/main_twopanes</item>
</resources>
```

If I try to compile this, I get an `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix` error.  Even after adding the namespace to the `resources` element, I get `error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'type' with value 'layout').`

[Elsewhere in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), they show a different and seemingly inverted and incorrect way to alias layouts:

> To create an alias to an existing layout, use the  element,
>   wrapped in a `<merge>`. For example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <merge>
>     <include layout="@layout/main_ltr"/>
> </merge>
> ```

Running this results in the following error in LogCat `E/AndroidRuntime(1558): android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true`.  So this error seems to reinforce the fact that this `<include>` `<merge>` pair must be a mistake, because it requires an unnecessary parent `View`.

Lastly there's the [`<merge>` documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge), which seems to contradict the former direction, making no mention of the inverted form of a top-level `<merge><include/></merge>`.

> To avoid including such a redundant view group, you can instead use
>   the  element as the root view for the re-usable layout. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/add"/>
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/delete"/>
>
> </merge>
> ```

Comment: The [first method](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) seems to compile and work fine for me. Do you have the latest SDK Tools installed?

Comment: @Joe thanks for verifying this!  It ends up I didn't read the instructions carefully.  I did what I thought I should do--put the layout.xml inside the `layout-large` rather than `values-large` folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first technique works, you just have to put your `<resources>` file in the correct folder.  It should be in the `values` folders not the `layout` folders as you might when reusing layouts via `<include>`.

For instance, suppose you have a layout named `editor.xml` that lives in the `layout` folder.  Suppose you want to use a specialized layout on `small` and `normal` screen sizes.  If you didn't care about repeating yourself, you would just copy and paste this layout into the `layout-small` and `layout-normal` folders and name it `editor.xml` in each folder.  So you'd have three files named `editor.xml`.

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you would place the specialized layout in the main `layout` folder and name it, say, `compact_editor.xml`.  Then you'd create a file named `layout.xml` in the `values-small` and `values-normal` folders.  Each file would read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="editor" type="layout">@layout/compact_editor</item>
</resources>
```

I've filed a [documentation issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38308) about the other two problems.

Comment: "this inverted use of merge seems to be undocumented otherwise" -- the reason the `<merge>` is needed is that `<include>` is not supported as a root element, for some reason. Otherwise, this use of `<merge>` is normal. `<merge>` says "here's a bunch of widgets and containers that need to go in some indeterminate parent", with `<merge>` serving as the root XML element (since XML needs one). In this case, the "bunch of widgets and containers" happen to be stored in another layout resource, hence the `<include>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sounds reasonable, but this is your interpretation based on your understanding of `<merge>` not its [actual documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge).

Comment: Well, the actual documentation isn't exactly going to win a prize, but there is nothing in there that I see that contradicts what I wrote.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, note [this new issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38312): Support <include> as a top-level element so we don't need to surround it with <merge>

Comment: @CommonsWare You're probably tired of discussing this, but after actually testing the second option in a `ListView`, the inflater fails.  See my question edit:  Running this results in the following error in LogCat E/AndroidRuntime(1558): android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true. So this error seems to reinforce the fact that this <include> <merge> pair must be a mistake, because it requires an unnecessary parent View.

Comment: The `<merge><inflate/></merge>` definitely works with `setContentView()`, as I tested that before commenting. I can see where it might not work with `inflate(R.layout.alias, parent, false)`.

Comment: @CommonsWare So first, this approach can't work from a `ListView` row.  But in defense of the documentation, they didn't advertise that it would.  More importantly though, doesn't this then create a possibly unnecessary layer of `ViewGroup` even when it does work?  There's the parent's `ViewGroup` as well as the one in the included file.  I was pleased to learn that the first resources strategy actually does work--it was my error.

Comment: "More importantly though, doesn't this then create a possibly unnecessary layer of ViewGroup even when it does work? There's the parent's ViewGroup as well as the one in the included file." -- it should not add any more layers than you would have in referring to the original resource. All that being said, any chance I can con you into adding an update to your question with the proper syntax for what you got working? I haven't seen that approach before. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Though in the particular scenario you outlined, the simpler solution would be to have `res/layout/editor.xml` (for small/normal) and `res/layout-large/editor.xml` (for large/xlarge). Then, you do not need the alias. That being said, layout aliases will be very useful when mixing and matching other resource set qualifiers, like the `-swNNNdp` stuff.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod did you mean to say `values-small` and `values-normal`? Otherwise that is identical to the original documentation, no? I will do an edit to this answer to use their example with what you propose is the solution in the first paragraph (and seems to work for my project)

Comment: @DandreAllison yes, thanks, it should have read `values`, not `layout`.  I've corrected it.  If you'd like to add anything else, please do so in a new answer or comments.  Thanks!